# inserting struct pointer to vector

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I'm trying to make a list of struct pointer using `vector`. My struct contains some fields like

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<vector>
#define MAX 100

struct Student {
    char* name,
    *phoneNum,
    *address
};
```

I have a utility function that helps init for struct pointer

```
struct Student* newStudent() {
    struct Student* pStudent = NULL;
    pStudent = (struct Student*)malloc(sizeof(struct Student));
    pStudent->name = (char*)malloc(MAX * sizeof(char));
    pStudent->phoneNum = (char*)malloc(MAX * sizeof(char));
    pStudent->address = (char*)malloc(MAX * sizeof(char));
  
    return pStudent;
}
```

inserting function is like

```
void insert(vector<Student*> &listStudents, Student* pStudent) {
    printf("name: "); scanf("%s\n" , pStudent->name);
    printf("phone number: "); scanf("%s\n", pStudent->phoneNum);
    printf("address: "); scanf("%s\n", pStudent->address);
    listStudents.push_back(pStudent);
    printf("inserted OK!\n");
    printf("Size: %lu\n", listStudents.size());
}
```

and display function

```
void display(vector<Student*>& listStudents) {
    printf("total students: %lu\n", listStudents.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < listStudents.size(); i++) {
        printf("Student %d\n", i+1);
        printf("name: %s\n", listStudents[i]->name);
        printf("phone number: %s\n", listStudents[i]->phoneNum);
        printf("address %s\n", listStudents[i]->address);
    } 
}
```

here is my main function

```
int main() {
   
   Student* pStudent = newStudent();
   vector<Student*> listStudents;
   while(true) {
        int op1;
        printf("\n1. input\n2. output\n3. search\n4. erase\n5. end\n");
        printf("option: "); 
        scanf("%d", &op1);
        switch(op1) {
            case 1:
                insert(listStudents, pStudent);
                break;
            case 2:
                display(listStudents);
                break;
            default:
                printf("invalid option!\n");
                break;
        }
    }
    
    free(pStudent);
}
```

when I tried to insert some information into each field. It's was fine. But when I displayed it
out. The results are duplicated. For example:

`insert`:

```
Student 1:
name: A
phone number: 010...
address: xyz

Student 2:
name: B 
phone number: 011...
address: zyz
```

`display` the result was

```
Student 1:
name: B 
phone number: 011...
address: zyz 

Student 2:
name: B 
phone number: 011...
address: zyz
```

What's wrong with that??

Comment: Pleae make a [mre].

Comment: `insert` just pushes the  argument-provided student object pointer into the vector. You pass the *same* object pointer with each iteration, changing its *content* along the way. As a result, your vector is filled with (a) the same pointer duplicated over and over, and (b) the pointed-to object contains whatever was read *last*. Why you're mashing C and C++ concepts in this is a bigger mystery.

Comment: Consider just how many `Student` objects are ever created in your code since the call to `newStudent()` happens once.

Comment: If you are using C++ for vector, why can't use use proper C++ for the `Student` struct. Namely, a constructor, new instead of malloc, or better yet,  just use `std::string` instead of `char*` .  Not to mention `cout` instead of `printf`.  You'll save many lines of code...

Comment: **What's wrong with that??** You are making a big mess of mixing c++ and c. Why.... ?

Comment: Don't mix C++ and C, do as selbie suggested, otherwise code will always be an utter garbage. If you're learning from a school teacher sorry but it's a terrible way to do that and your teacher do have to update his skill.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you have a single instance of the student class and you write over that. In C++, classes usually have value semantics. You usually don't manage your own memory. Here's a more idiomatic implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Student final {
 private:
  std::string m_name;
  std::string m_phoneNum;
  std::string m_address;

 public:
  Student(std::string name, std::string phoneNum, std::string address)
      : m_name(std::move(name)),
        m_phoneNum(std::move(phoneNum)),
        m_address(std::move(address)) {}

  auto& Name() const noexcept { return m_name; }

  auto& PhoneNumber() const noexcept { return m_phoneNum; }

  auto& Address() const noexcept { return m_address; }
};

Student GetStudent() {
  std::string name, num, addr;
  std::cout << "Name: ";
  std::cin >> name;
  std::cout << "Phone nnumber: ";
  std::cin >> num;
  std::cout << "Address: ";
  std::cin >> addr;
  Student st(std::move(name), std::move(num), std::move(addr));
  return st;
}

int main() {
  std::cin.exceptions(std::istream::failbit | std::istream::badbit);

  std::vector<Student> vec;
  vec.push_back(GetStudent());
  vec.push_back(GetStudent());
  vec.push_back(GetStudent());

  for (auto const& elm : vec) {
    std::cout << "Name: " << elm.Name() << "\nPhone: " << elm.PhoneNumber()
              << "\nAddress: " << elm.Address() << '\n';
  }
}
```

This also solves many other bugs:

- Your `scanf` calls are subject to buffer overflow
- `lu` is not the correct specifier for `size_t`
- You leak the string members (all of them)
- You don't check for `nullptr` after `malloc`
- Your code is not exception safe
- `printf` should either be flushed explicitly, or you should end it with `'\n'`  before calling `scanf`.

and possibly more.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I have an idea about using class. But I just want to try with `struct pointer` and see how it works.

Comment: @KeinKeinKein it's possible to make it work. It's just harder.

Comment: yeah, the above guys just pointed out my mistake that is I used duplicated struct pointer for every inserting data. So when printed out the results are the same. But anyway thank you the the kind!

Comment: @KeinKeinKein doing it the "C way" is not inherently bad. It is just more difficult. You have to keep track of many little things, all those pointers, and if you get them wrong, it fails silently. If you are in the "++ Land", you might as well do it the C++ way. Otherwise you could use the C language to begin with. I did point out lots of bugs in your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

As @WhozCraig mentioned in his comment, you are changing the same struct pointer. You must allocate different struct pointer each time. Your main function should look like this,

```
int main() {
   vector<Student*> listStudents;
   while(true) {
        int op1;
        printf("\n1. input\n2. output\n3. search\n4. erase\n5. end\n");
        printf("option: "); 
        scanf("%d", &op1);
        switch(op1) {
            case 1: {
                Student* pStudent = newStudent();
                insert(listStudents, pStudent);
                break;
            }
            case 2:
                display(listStudents);
                break;
            default:
                printf("invalid option!\n");
                break;
        }
    }
    
    for (const auto& pointers: listStudents)
        free(pointers)
}
```

You have to allocate a new struct pointer each time user enters 1.

Comment: @Thanks for your comment! But put the object inside `switch's case like above cause `It will cause a "crosses initialization error`.

Comment: Ok. So there'll be another edit. I'll edit and fix the code.

Comment: No there'll not be a error because the scope of the variable is local.